# Give an example of a nonempty subset of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give an example of a non empty subset of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.

I know that $\mathbb Z =$ integers positive and negative plus $O$.

A subset of $\mathbb Z$ is for example $\{\ldots, -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3, \ldots \}$. How do I write a subset of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?

Comment: How about $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$?

Comment: $S=(0,0,0)$ for one.

Comment: Can you write down one element of $\mathbb{Z}^3$?

Comment: @lulu.  (0,0,0) is not a subset of ZxZxZ.  It is an element of ZxZxZ.

Answer (score 4):

If $A= \{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3,4,5\}$ and $C=\{7\}$ then $$A\times B\times C = \{(1,3,7),(1,4,7),(1,5,7),(2,3,7),(2,4,7),(2,5,7) \}$$ is an example of a subset of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 4):

Take nonempty subsets $A,B,C \subseteq \mathbb Z$ and then show that $A \times B \times C \subseteq \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is nonempty.

---

edit: As a bonus you may try to find a subset of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ that can not be written in the form above.